# How do I get the month to stop displaying 1.00, 2.00, ... etc

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++ and I am writing a program that calculates the balance of a savings account at the end of a three-month period. I am supposed to use loops, which I have done and don't have much of a problem. The problem I am having is that all the numbers for deposit, withdrawal, current balance, etc. are supposed to be displayed as x.xx, and I am getting that output, but it also does that for the month. How do I make it so that the month doesn't display as x.xx?
Here's my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double startbalance;
    double annualrate;
    double monthlyrate;
    double deposit;
    double withdrawal;
    double totaldeposit = 0;
    double totalwithdrawal = 0;
    double totalinterest = 0;
    double monthstart = 0;
    double monthend = 0;
    printf("Welcome to Your Bank!\n");
    cout << "What is your starting Balance? $";
    cin >> startbalance;
    cout << "What is the annual interest rate?. Please enter whole value. For example 6 for 6% :";
    cin >> annualrate;
    monthend += startbalance;
    for (double month = 1; month <= 3; month++)
    {
        cout << "Month #" << month << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Current Balance: $" << monthend << endl;
            cout << "Please enter total amount of deposits: $";
            cin >> deposit;

            if (deposit < 0)
            {
                cout << "Deposit must be a positive number!\n";
            }
        } while (deposit < 0);
        totaldeposit += deposit;
        monthend += deposit;
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter total amount of withdrawals: $";
            cin >> withdrawal;
            if (withdrawal < 0 || withdrawal > monthend)
            {
                cout << "Withdrawal must be a positive number and not be larger than balance: $" << monthend << endl;
            }
        } while (withdrawal < 0 || withdrawal > totaldeposit);
        cout << endl;
        totalwithdrawal += withdrawal;
        monthend -= withdrawal;
        monthlyrate = ((monthstart + monthend) / 2 * (annualrate / 12));
        totalinterest += monthlyrate;
        cout << "New Balance: $" << monthend << "\n";

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Start Balance:         " << setw(9) << "$" << startbalance << "\n";
    cout << "Total Deposits:        " << setw(9) << "$" << totaldeposit << "\n";
    cout << "Total Withdrawals:     " << setw(9) << "$" << totalwithdrawal << "\n";
    cout << "Total Interest Earned: " << setw(9) << "$" << totalinterest << "\n";
    cout << "Final balance:         " << setw(9) << "$" << monthend << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `month` should not be a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type-cast your month variable to int before displaying.

```
cout << "Month #" << (int)month << endl;
```

That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make monthend an int or a long. .........

Comment: No he can't.  The variable `monthend` is part of the money calculation.  You mean the for loop index variable `month` don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Please make Data Type of your `month` as `int` instead of `double`.

`double` is a floating point data type. `int` is a whole number like 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. `Double` is numbers with decimals like 1.1 or 45.564, `float` is a even more specific version of `double`

Example:

```
//if you just going to work with whole numbers
int a;
a = 1

//if you're working with numbers with a bit more precision
float b;
b = 1.1234

//if you're working with numbers with massive precision.. 
double c;
c = 1.123456
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around? float is less precise than double as float is typically 4 bytes where double is 8 bytes.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Correct. Had it put upside down. thanks a lot. upvoted your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your variable types seem to be fine for the calculation; I believe your problem is within this statement:

> ```
> for (double month = 1; month <= 3; month++) {
>     cout << "Month #" << month << endl;
> ```

it is within your loop as why your month is printing out: `1.0`, `2.0` etc.

change it to this:

```
 for ( int month = 1; month <=3; month++ ) {
     cout << "Month #" << month << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically, variable *month* should be an integer.
Declare its datatype as *int* instead of *double*.